# Unable to activate a Service in a Project using BIM 360 APIs

Tags: autodesk-bim360

**Question:**
After adding a new BIM 360 Docs project using the API, how do I activate it for Document Management using the APIs? Following online tutorial does not yield expected results.

**Background:**
I was trying to follow a tutorial to create a BIM 360 Docs project and activate it for Document Management, as it's listed [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/create-project/). Project creation itself is a breeze, however the step required to activate a service does not work [as outlined](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/activate-service/).

Here are my individual steps:

1. **Create BIM 360 Project** with `HTTP POST https://{{ForgeURL}}/hq/v1/accounts/{{AccountId}}/projects`

Created project information is returned in the response, including new project id and status, which is *pending*.

2. Attempt to add project admin and activate a service as outlined [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/activate-service/)

i. **Add Project Admin - Method 1** - Documentation [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/) lists endpoint capable of *adding a project admin to a specific BIM 360 project and service type*.

`HTTP POST https://{{ForgeURL}}/hq/v1/accounts/{{AccountId}}/projects/{{BIM360ProjectId}}/users`

```
{
    "role":"project_admin",
    "service_type":"doc_manager",
    "company_id":"{{BIM360CompanyId}}",
    "email":"user@email.com"
}
```

Response: HTTP 404 Not Found

```
{
    "code": 1004,
    "message": "this project doesn't exist."
}
```

ii. **Add Project Admin - Method 2** - Documentation [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/) lists endpoint capable of *adding users (project admin and project user) to a project*.

`HTTP POST https://{{ForgeURL}}/hq/v2/accounts/{{AccountId}}/projects/{{BIM360ProjectId}}/users/import`

```
[
 {
   "email": "user@email.com",
   "services": {
     "document_management": {
       "access_level": "admin"
     },
     "project_administration": {
       "access_level": "admin"
     }
   },
   "company_id": "{{BIM360CompanyId}}",
   "industry_roles": []
 }
]
```

Response: HTTP 200 OK, but... it's a *failure*

```
{
    "failure": 1,
    "success": 0,
    "success_items": [],
    "failure_items": [
        {
            "email": "user@email.com",
            "services": {
                "document_management": {
                    "access_level": "admin"
                },
                "project_administration": {
                    "access_level": "admin"
                }
            },
            "company_id": "716a5472-a69c-4c07-aa0c-9e54e98ff28f",
            "industry_roles": [],
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "Services [\"document_management\"] are not active or pending in project",
                    "code": 2000
                }
            ],
            "project_id": "1b6f2179-8f2f-4fa7-907b-901aee7224be",
            "account_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

One can see that it complains about *Services [\"document_management\"] are not active or pending in project*. `project_administration` had to be included, otherwise it would have also complained about *service `project_administration` required if any `access_level` is set as `admin`*.

However, I can see the project using BIM 360 Docs web app Account Admin though as *Inactive*.

Attempt to activate a project using `HTTP PATCH https://{{ForgeURL}}/hq/v1/accounts/{{AccountId}}/projects/{{BIM360ProjectId}}` returns

```
{
    "code": 1001,
    "message": "You cannot change the status of a project that has no project admin."
}
```

iii. **Add Project Admin - Method 3** - Documentation [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-user_id-PATCH/) lists endpoint capable of *updating a user’s profile for a project, including the user’s access level for the project (admin or user)*.

`HTTP PATCH https://{{ForgeURL}}/hq/v2/accounts/{{AccountId}}/projects/{{BIM360ProjectId}}/users/{{BIM360UserId}}`

```
 {
   "services": {
     "document_management": {
       "access_level": "user"
     }
   },
   "company_id": "{{BIM360CompanyId}}"
 }
```

Response: HTTP 200 OK, but it's a *failure*

```
{
    "account_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "project_id": "1b6f2179-8f2f-4fa7-907b-901aee7224be",
    "error": [
        {
            "message": "User does not exist in project",
            "code": 2000
        },
        {
            "message": "Services [\"document_management\"] are not active or pending in project",
            "code": 2000
        }
    ]
}
```

Long story short, I am unable to add project admin using any of the methods available.

What's more, when I add a Project Administrator there using *Project Admin \ Services \ Document Management* section the project status turns into *Active* and I am suddenly able to activate a service as outlined [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/activate-service/).

Comment: Could you try: 1) create a project, 2) add admin, 3) add doc as service.  API is like automating the user actions here.  in UI, it looks like this: 
 https://help.autodesk.com/view/BIM360D/ENU/?guid=GUID-9C991F4C-7012-4770-B8F7-A1D45F5D9197

Comment: @MikakoHarada thanks for prompt response. Unfortunately, I am unable to complete step 2) add admin. I added more details in the original question, please refer to 2 i-iii above and let me know what's the correct way of adding project administrators using BIM 360 API.

Comment: Method 1 works for me. Could you make sure you pick up the project id from the response id?  (When I made a mistake with project id, I got a message project not found.)

Comment: I double checked my calls and the project id is correct as taken from the response id. I shared more information in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [endpoint documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/create-project/) has incorrect information pointing to payload containing

```
"service_types": "field"
```

creating a BIM 360 project with the project information that is accessible and available for **all BIM 360 services**, which is not what happens. One has to explicitly specify service type, e.g.

```
"service_types": "doc_manager"
```

or according to [this documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/)

> If nothing specified, the project will be created for all the enabled
>   services in the account.

This allows to add a project admin using a **Method 1** outlined in my question.